# How to update column values between two values of another column within the same table?

Tags: kdb

Apologies for my poor English as it is not my first language.

I have a table that notes the price of a stock when my signal fires `signal` and two columns that add/subtract a small amount to this value to act as my take profit `tp` and stop loss `sl`.

Another column tracks the rolling price of this stock `price` and when the take profit or stop loss is hit during the life-time of the signal, then the `action` column will identify this.

The table looks like the below:

```
 price | signal |   tp   |   sl   | action |
--------------------------------------------
0.6623 | 0.6623 | 0.6633 | 0.6613 |    `   |
0.6627 |   0n   | 0.6633 | 0.6613 |    `   |
0.6630 |   0n   | 0.6633 | 0.6613 |    `   |
0.6631 |   0n   | 0.6633 | 0.6613 |    `   |
0.6639 |   0n   | 0.6633 | 0.6613 |   `TP  |
0.6641 |   0n   | 0.6633 | 0.6613 |   `TP  |
0.6638 | 0.6638 | 0.6648 | 0.6628 |    `   |
```

As you can see, based on other logic my signal triggered in the first and last row, and the take-profit was met twice in this span as per the `action` column. I would only like it to trigger once from the time a signal starts till it ends, that is it would be hit in the 5th row but the 6th and all subsequent rows till the next time `signal` has a non-null value, at which point it would recommence again.

I tried to do something simple such as `xprev` so that it does not trigger if the previous value is non-null, but sometimes it skips a row and it also does not seem like the most intuitive solution.

I think a function would work best but I am not exactly proficient with Q so happy to learn something new.

Comment: Hi, in general, please include a copy pasteable code snippet to generate your sample data set so that others can help more easily.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution which updates the action after the fact;

```
q)t:([]p:1 2 3 4 4.5 4.5 5 4 4.5 4.5;s:1 0n 0n 0n 0n 0n 5 0n 0n 0n;tp:4 4 4 4 4 4 6 4 4 4;sl:1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 1 1;action:10#`)

q)t
p   s tp sl action
------------------
1   1 4  1
2     4  1
3     4  1
4     4  1
4.5   4  1
4.5   4  1
5   5 6  5
4     4  1
4.5   4  1
4.5   4  1

q)show t:update action:?[tp<=p;`TP;?[sl>p;`SL;`]] by s from t
p   s tp sl action
------------------
1   1 4  1
2     4  1
3     4  1
4     4  1  TP
4.5   4  1  TP
4.5   4  1  TP
5   5 6  5
4     4  1  TP
4.5   4  1  TP
4.5   4  1  TP

q)show t:update action:` from t where not i in raze value exec i where 1<deltas i by s from t where action<>`
p   s tp sl action
------------------
1   1 4  1
2     4  1
3     4  1
4     4  1  TP
4.5   4  1
4.5   4  1
5   5 6  5
4     4  1  TP
4.5   4  1
4.5   4  1
```

Comment: `where not i in value exec first i by s from a where action` -->  just a little confused by this as shouldn't it be `from t` rather than `from a`? Not sure what `a` represents and if it is an object or a variable?

Comment: Sorry, good spot @vicefreak04. Typo on my part - I'll correct inline now, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Easiest to split this into two seperate update statements. The logic you need for only keeping the first instance comes from: https://code.kx.com/phrases/flag/#invert-1s-after-first-1

```
q)t:([]price:0.6623 0.6627 0.6630 0.6631 0.6639 0.6641 0.6638;signal:0.6623 0n 0n 0n 0n 0n 0.6638;tp:0.6633 0.6633 0.6633 0.6633 0.6633 0.6633 0.6648;sl:0.6613 0.6613 0.6613 0.6613 0.6613 0.6613 0.6628)
q)iaf:{til[count x]=x?1b}    // invert 1s after first 1
q)
q)t:update action:``TP iaf price>tp by fills signal from t
q)update action:``SL iaf price<sl by fills signal from t where null action
price  signal tp     sl     action
----------------------------------
0.6623 0.6623 0.6633 0.6613
0.6627        0.6633 0.6613
0.663         0.6633 0.6613
0.6631        0.6633 0.6613
0.6639        0.6633 0.6613 TP
0.6641        0.6633 0.6613
0.6638 0.6638 0.6648 0.6628
```